# How to use autotools for deep projects?

Tags: c, autotools

I have a **C** project that has the following structure

```
Main/
  Makefile.am
  bin/
  src/
     Makefile.am
     main.c
     SomeLibrarySource/
         SomeFuncs.c
         SomeFuncs.h
```

The **main.c** contains the main function that uses functions defined in the **SomeFuncs.{h/c}** files.

I want to use autotools for this project. I read a couple of resources on autotools. But, I was only able to manage using `autotools` for a single level project where all source, object and other files reside in the same directory.

Then I got some links that talked about using autotools for deep projects like this one and then I got confused.

Right now I have two Makefile.am as follows

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS=src
```

**src/Makefile.am**

```
mainprgdir=../
mainprg_PROGRAMS=main
main_SOURCES=main.c
```

I am pretty sure that these files should not be as I have them now **:P**

How do I use **autotools** for the above project structure? (At least what should be there in those **`Makefile.am`**(s) and where should I place them.

EDIT:
One more thing! At the end I would like to have the object files created in the **bin** directory.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of autotools, write a clean, simple configuration shell script by hand. This will be less effort in the long run. Also, find and read the paper *Recursive Make Considered Harmful*. It's best if you have a single set of rules linked to a master `Makefile` at the root of the project. There can be other makefiles, but these are just included by the master one, and contribute to one big tree of dependencies. Do not call `make` as a command from within `Makefile`, in other words.

Comment: Also, you don't have to have a `Makefile.am`. That is a template file for `automake`. You can use Autoconf without Automake.  An approach that is not bad is to have a `Makefile` which is not generated. The configurable make variables go into a `config.make` (generated from `config.make.in`) and that `config.make` is `include`-d from `Makefile`. If you must use autotools, keep it simple.

Comment: @Kaz Thanks for your comments. I will take care of these in future projects. For this one, I am doing recursive make, just for the heck of it. Just want to learn how it's done!

Comment: Don't specify where to put your object files. People might be trying to build your program in a location where the `bin/` directory is not writable. If you personally prefer them there, then `cd bin && ../configure`, but don't force that preference on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main approaches.  If the functions in SomeLibrarySource are used only by main, then there's no need to build a separate library and you can simply specify the source files in src/Makefile.am

```
main_SOURCES = main.c SomeLibrarySource/SomeFuncs.c
```

However, if you actually want to use the functions in other code in your tree, you do not want to compile SomeFuncs.c multiple times but should use a convenience library.

```
# Assigning main_SOURCES is redundant
main_SOURCES = main.c
main_LDADD = SomeLibrarySource/libSomeFuncs.a
noinst_LIBRARIES = SomeLibrarySource/libSomeFuncs.a
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(srcdir)/SomeLibrarySource
```

(You'll need AC_PROG_RANLIB in configure.ac to use convenience libraries.)
If the source file is named SomeFuncs.c, automake will not need Makefile.am to specify `SomeLibrarySource_libSomeFuncs_a_SOURCES`, but if the name of the source code file does not match the name specified in `noinst_LIBRARIES`, `SomeLibrarySource_libSomeFuncs_a_SOURCES` should be set to the list of files used to build the library.  Note that you do not need to specify main_SOURCES, since main.c is the default value if left unspecified  (but it's not a bad idea to be explicit.)  (In all of this, I am not comfortable use CamlCase names, but the system I'm using uses a case insensitive file system (biggest mistake apple ever made) and the examples I give here are working for me.  YMMV)

You could of course do a recursive make, or build the library as a separate project and install it.  (I like the final option.  Libraries with useful features should exist on their own.)

Answer (score 2):

`mainprogdir=../` does not make a whole lot of sense (you don't know what it is relative to on installation). Probably intended:

```
# Main/Makefile.am
# .━━ target for `make install`
# |
# ↓              ↓━━ target for compilation
bin_PROGRAMS = bin/main

# ↓━━ based upon compilation target name
bin_main_SOURCES = src/main.c
```